# Can't write on a file after I pass its fstream to a function

Tags: c++, file

I have a problem with read and write file. When I pass a fstream object that initially read from the file and then try to write on the same file, the writing fails and nothing is written in the file. I specify that no errors are displayed.

Minimal reproductive example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void test_function(std::fstream& file);

int main() {

std::fstream file;
file.open("file_name.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);

test_function(file);
file << "Test string 2" << '\n';
return 0;

}

void test_function(std::fstream& file) {
std::string line;
file.get();
std::getline(file,line);
std::cout << line << '\n';
file << "Test string" << '\n';
}
```

Both "Test string" and "Test string 2" aren't written on the file.
Line is displayed.

After some test I notice that if I add in the MRE test_function the following line of code: file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end); after the read operations and before the writing operations all the "Test string" are written successfully but I can't explain why.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. If it only doesn't work when outputting after the `Universita::getID` call, it seems that the problem is inside that function.

Comment: Do you have the `getID` code? Could it be that it's closing the file as a side effect?

Comment: Thank to all, I just update the question with the code of getID

Comment: It's still not a [mre] though

Comment: You are right, I have some difficulty to recreate the problem.

Comment: My advice would be 1) identify a case when you cannot write to `database` after calling `getID`, and then 2) debug `getID`.

Comment: I add some 'database << "1";' line in different place of getID. The one before the first if when I use database.peek, write the "1" on the file, the ramaing ones after the if write nothing

Comment: Now I notice that if I add in the MRE test_function the following line of code: file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end); all the Test string are written successfully.

Comment: *"I use a function, not a metod of a class but the problem is the same"* -- this is good. Now you can get rid of the initial example so we can focus on the simpler code. You might also want to take the opportunity to make your opening paragraph -- the first thing people see -- more engaging and informative (c.f. [ask]).